# Sharepoint 2010 Custom Field type

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I tried creating a custom frield type using the articles "[Creating a Custom Field Type for SharePoint 2010 (Email Validation Field)"](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Roji.Joy/creating-a-custom-field-type-for-sharepoint-2010-email-validation-field/) and MSDN article "[Creating Custom SharePoint 2010 Field Types"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg132914%28v=office.14%29.aspx). In both cases I dont see any build /deployment errors. But still I dont see the custom field type in the list of options when I try to create a new column. Do I need to do anything on the Central Adinistration to make this work. Please help me with this.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but has the feature been activated in Site collection features

Comment: I started from the scratch again and now i see the custom field but data is not getting saved now. I have updated my question with code.

Comment: Everythings works fine now. I Was not getting the value from the textbox before updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working fine now. Other than the steps mentioned in the articles I also added below code.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

            // add save handler only in New and Edit modes
            if ((SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.New)
                || (SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Edit))
            {
                SPContext.Current.FormContext.OnSaveHandler
                    += new EventHandler(MyCustomSaveHandler);
            }
        }

        protected void MyCustomSaveHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.Validate();
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                SPContext.Current.ListItem["CM_x0020_Number"] = TextBox1.Text;
                SPContext.Current.ListItem.Update();
            }
            else
            {
                // do actions instead of save
            }
        }
```